# How to setup retries and timeout in trest and trestclient in Talend?

Tags: talend

I have a job which uses `tRestClient` to get a token, then uses `tRest` to get data from CRM based on the token. Both of these components seem to timeout sometimes while connecting to CRM. How can I set them up to have 10 retries for the connection and more minutes to wait before they timeout?

Comment: try taking the loop method in the other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53290472/how-to-implement-tloop-in-talendquestion you asked and checking in the tJava if the value is there, sleeping 5 sec between each iteration

Comment: in tRestClient, I've increased connection timeout and receive timeout.  But for looping tRest, do I need to put the tjava between tRest and tExtractJSONfields?  My job is:  Prejob--->Calling joblet(which is tRestClient)  Then tSetGlobalvar--->tRest--->tExtractJSONField---tJavaRow(Here it is breaking CRM picklist information into separate rows)--->tmap--->tMssqloutput.

Answer (score 0):

There is some setting to do that.
Check the documentation here:

https://help.talend.com/reader/7NvFnkWpbH8Gy3Rm6mUXnw/ECeCwoP1aVopmhqJe_dENA.

You need to go in the advanced setting in the component.
Moreover, there is some limitation to the studio like you see in the documentation.