# How to implement tLoop in Talend?

Tags: talend

I'm new to Talend and need an example job to implement `tLoop`. I want to run a job 10 times if it fails.  I've looked at the documents, but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Just use a tLoop -> tRunJob and the exit condition is based on the error/exit code of the tRunJob It's really easy.

Answer (score 5):

This answer has 2 sections

1. Creating a loop with tJava
2. Retying a failed connection to a data source 5 times (with adding **tJavaFlex**)

**___________________________________**

**SECTION 1 : Creating a loop with tJava**

**-----------------------------------------------------------**

I just write a tJava component and then iterate to false. 
Like this

**Step 1:** create a context variable

[image]

**Step 2:** write some java code in tJava (tJava1)

```
// setting loop flag
context.continueLooping = true;
//log.info("Starting job...");
```

then connect `On Component Ok`

[image]

**Step 3:** Create the tLoop

in the loop condition put your context `context.continueLooping`
which should be true by the first iteration.

[image]

then iterate

[image]

to the next tJava (tJava2)

```
if ( ((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 1)
{
   // code

}
else if(((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 2) 
{
   // code

}
else if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 3)
{
   // code

}
else if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 4)
{
   // code

}
else if (((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) == 5)
{
   // code

   context.continueLooping = false;
  // log.info("DONE");
}

else 
{
   context.continueLooping = false;
  // log.error("out of bounds...");

}
```

this tJava runs different code for each iteration till it reaches 5 
I use this area to count stuff and load value to other contexts and more.

Then it runs the nest part n times till the context value is set to false.

[image]

**___________________________**

**SECTION 2 : TO Retry Failed Connections**

**___________________________**

if you need to retry a  DB connection.

add a tJavaFlex between tLoop1 and tJava2 like so

[image]

and add the following code in the 3 sections 
Start:

```
// start part of your Java code
try{
```

Main:

```
// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
if ( ((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) > 1)
{
Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

End:

```
// end of the component, outside/closing the loop
}catch (Exception e) {

if ( ((Integer)globalMap.get("tLoop_1_CURRENT_ITERATION")) > 5)
{
context.continueLooping = false;
}
else
{
System.out.println("Connection failed. Retrying...next");
}


}
```

and add `On Component Ok` `tJava` with the code to stop looping on the success (tJava3)

```
context.continueLooping = false;
```

Comment: This works, but when I put tMSSqlConnection between tLoop and 2nd tjava, it seems not to work.  What I'm trying to accomplish is, if a connection fails retry 10 times before failing a job.  If you have something like this in a sample job, please post.

Comment: I added a section 2 to my first answer : add a (tJavaFlex)

Comment: Thanks for the above job, it is working as expected.  If my connection fails after even 10 retries, I would like to send the error message via tLogcather what caused a connection issue.  Meaning a password expired, etc...   I have a parent job that has a tLogcather calling a childjob which include the above job in it.